# How to integrate twilio voice call in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I want to implement twilio voice call in the flutter application. I tried a lot but can not get success on it.

I tried below packages for the integration twilio voice call.

```
firebase_core: ^1.18.0
firebase_messaging: ^11.4.2
cloud_functions: ^3.2.17
firebase_auth: ^3.3.20
```

Please help me to integrate this in flutter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[I create a package for this a long time ago](https://github.com/Pierre-Monier/twilio_programmable_voice-1), it's not production ready but maybe you can get some inspiration from it. The main thing is that there is no official twilio API for Flutter. So you can either try to find an out of the box package for it, or you can write the code yourself.

If you write the code yourself, you will have to write native code on the platform you are targeting in order to call the existing Twilio API for the platform. Basically you will write a bridge for each platform you want to target. You can do that with [MethodChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html) and other out of the box API provide by flutter. You can learn more about that by digging into the package

Answer (score 1):

Twilio doesn't have an officially supported library for Flutter. As well as Pierre's suggestion, there is this [unofficial Twilio Voice Flutter library](https://github.com/diegogarciar/twilio_voice) which might help you out too.